# Create node using services

Tags: nodes, services

I want to create a mobile application using my drupal application. For the communication I use the module services. The connection system works with success. This return this result.

```
    {
  "sessid": "98gnwpE1GeguxN1y4t0WkWhDzK-C-Ashbn5GExj9l7M",
  "session_name": "SESS7609adb25a00cf561a9d882a31e81d29",
  "token": "aK4L6D1APRH16lGSAirIaZVGR02T5gs8DeE5jffYCKI",
  "user": {
    "uid": "30",
    "name": "admin",
    "mail": "zinalacina@gmail.com",
    "theme": "",
    "signature": "",
    "signature_format": "filtered_html",
    "created": "1486745824",
    "access": "1487091377",
    "login": 1487154223,
    "status": "1",
    "timezone": "Africa/Ouagadougou",
    "language": "en",
    "picture": null,
    "init": "zinalacina@gmail.com",
    "data": {
      "ckeditor_default": "t",
      "ckeditor_show_toggle": "t",
      "ckeditor_width": "100%",
      "ckeditor_lang": "en",
      "ckeditor_auto_lang": "t",
      "contact": 1
    },
    "uuid": "14899bf3-1a0d-42b5-934e-650471d7da54",
    "roles": {
      "2": "authenticated user",
      "3": "administrator"
    },
    "rdf_mapping": {
      "rdftype": [
        "sioc:UserAccount"
      ],
      "name": {
        "predicates": [
          "foaf:name"
        ]
      },
      "homepage": {
        "predicates": [
          "foaf:page"
        ],
        "type": "rel"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to create a node type article and I use this method

```
POST: http://localhost/drupal-7/?q=my_endpoint/node.json
{"type":"article","title":"BEVVtDcZmL","language":"und"}
```

But the result

```
[
  "Access denied for user anonymous"
]
```

. I know it normal because he don't know who wants to create the node.
Now I question is how to parse sessionId or token to have the permission to create my node? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First thing you need to do is login via Services (unless you allow anonymous users permission to create content), which is a `POST` call to `?q=[my-endpoint]/user/login.json`
2. Once logged in, you need to retrieve a new CSRF token (this new token should be returned within the login result)
3. Then make a `POST` call to `?q=[my-endpoint]/node.json`, sending along something like this:

-

```
{
  title: "Hello world",
  type: "article",
  uid: 123,
  body: {
    und: [
      { value: 'How are you?' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Attach an `X-CSRF-Token` header to the request using the new token value generated after logging in.

That should then return something like this to you:

```
{
  nid: 456,
  uri: /* ... */
}
```

I have a blog post with examples of most of the Services Resources here: http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-services-examples

Comment: Thank you. I combined this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-drupal and your link http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile. I got the solution. Enormous thank. And I thanked you for good job.